# Strip http protocol from url before display in web2py?

Tags: python, http, url, web2py

When using [`IS_URL`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Validators) validator web2py prepends http to the stored value.  Now when forming a link in my view I'd like to remove the http and trailing slash.

```
<div>{{=A('<what goes here?>', _href=business.website)}}</div>
```

That is, given a url such as:

`http://www.example.com/`

I want the anchor text to be

`www.example.com` (or `example.com`)

I understand I can do this via standard python using [`urlparse.urlsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit), however wondering if web2py provides this functionality?

If using pure python is the best way to do this, where should the code to strip the url be? View? Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand I can do this via standard python using urlparse.urlsplit, however wondering if web2py provides this functionality?

No, web2py does not provide that functionality, so just use standard Python.

> If using pure python is the best way to do this, where should the code to strip the url be? View? Controller?

Your choice. If you do it in the view, you can avoid having to pass an additional variable from the controller.

Note, you can do `IS_URL(prepend_scheme=None)` if you want to prevent the validator from prepending the "http" (you can also set `prepend_scheme` to an alternative, such as "https").

Comment: What do you think of using adhoc object attributes rather than a second variable?  That is suppose the controller does `return dict(business=business)` and then you add `business.url_anchor_text = 'xyz'` before the return statement.   Do you think that is bad style?

Comment: If you want to take that approach, you might consider creating a virtual field to do so.